# Задание одинакового размера у картинок списка

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Здравствуйте, у меня есть список в нем выводятся справа картинки, но размеры у них разные, а мне нужно сделать одинакового размера. Подскажите, пожалуйста как это сделать.
Вот код :

```
  NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:mediaUrl_url];
  NSURLRequest *postRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL];
  NSURLResponse *response = nil;
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
  [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:responseData]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mediaUrl_url]];
UIImage *temp_image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:responseData ];
NSInteger imageWith = 50;
CGFloat scale = temp_image.size.width / imageWith;
[temp_image release];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData scale:scale];
[cell.imageView setImage:image];
```

Это не совсем красивое решение. Но в таблице метод `cell.imageView setFrame` не будет работать, а решение описанное [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992132/uiimageview-change-width-and-height) обрезает у изображения края.

Этот способ работает. Если кто знает метод получше, напишите. (самому интересно)